# how to add the label in both right and left in asp.net text box

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I try to add label in the right side as well of the text box to include the unit of the value.[I would like to have like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kHTJ.png)

and  [This code gives like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnJRc.png).

this is my code

```
    <div class="form-group ">

                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.files, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); }

                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.files, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control " } })<span>GB</span>
                        @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(true); }
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.files, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: in simply you can try by putting both controls in the  separate span tags, ie  
<span>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.files, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control " } })</span><span>GB</span>

Hope it will work not sure, just let me know if its works

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The class = "col-md-8" contains position:relative.
Since this line has class="form control " and your GB doesn't have a class. It goes to its natural position. Adding a class should tell it where to go.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.files, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-11" } })<span class="col-md-1">GB</span>
```